# how to convert a binary data into integer?

Tags: python

when I am using the `wave_read.readframes()` I am getting the result in binary data such as `/x00/x00/x00:/x16#/x05"`  etc a very long string

when asked for single frame it gives `@/x00` or `\xe3\xff` or so

I want this individual frame data in integer how can I convert them into integer to store them into array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021046/wav-file-manupalation/3021065

Comment: possible duplicate of [wav file manupalation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021046/wav-file-manupalation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each byte in its own int, then I'd go with map:

```
b = '\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
d = map(ord, b)
print d
[222, 173, 190, 239]
```

If, however, you are interested in more than 1 byte per int (or word, dword, etc), reduce could do you well (big-endian example):

```
reduce(lambda x, r: (x << 8) + r, d[1:3])
44478
```

Comment: You're still better off using the `struct` module instead of `reduce` and bit shifting if you're dealing with multibyte data. For example, reading 16-bit big-endian values: `struct.unpack('>{0}h'.format(len(b)/2), b)`.